# How to play streaming video on ipad using html5

Tags: html, video, streaming

I want to play a streaming video on my ipad for this i wrote this code but this is not working.

Please suggest what I am missing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="my_video_1" controls>
         <source src="http://vimeo.com/45578271" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>


</body>
</html>
```

I create a sample page for it os jsbin  http://jsbin.com/anevug

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working on any other browser either. Likely because `http://vimeo.com/45578271` is not a **video file**.

Comment: @deceze Is there any option by which i get exact location of video on vimeo or other website which provide free hosting for streaming video i am a newbie, please help

Comment: Why don't you use the embeddable code provided by Vimeo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you provide returns a `html` file, not a video file.
The `src` attribute requires the direct link to the video file, for example:

```
<source src="http://example.com/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```

When I open your Vimeo link:

```
http://vimeo.com/45578271
```

The actual video is downloaded from:

```
http://player.vimeo.com/play_redirect?clip_id=45578271&sig=ce8ba1a31d3d05b9f1df5672eab81d5f&time=1342087202&quality=sd&codecs=H264,VP8,VP6&type=moogaloop_local&embed_location=
```

This address changes however every time Vimeo is visited.
Vimeo does not allow [hot linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking) their content.

Comment: Is there any option by which i get exact location of video on vimeo or other website which provide free hosting for streaming video i am a newbie, please help

Comment: You can get the video location, it changes however every time the Vimeo page is visited, probably to prevent hot linking. Therefor you cannot play videos hosted by Vimeo on your website. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, http://vimeo.com/45578271 is not a video file, it's a link to another website.

Secondly, HTML5 itself doesn't support streaming. You have to use streaming protocols (for example RTP/RTSP/RTCP) or outside application to support it, like a streaming server of some sorts.

One guess would be to go with a Flash Streaming Server. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediastreaming/

I don't know too much about this myself, but for what your needs most likely are, and what I've heard about these servers, this would be a good one to look at and use as one of the comparison products (should you be doing research on other ones).

*"Adobe® Flash® Media Streaming Server 3 software is the affordable next step up from using progressive download to deliver video. It offers dramatically improved performance, more secure streaming, live streaming enhancements, industry-standard H.264 and HE-AAC support, and streaming delivery to mobile phones with Adobe Flash Lite™ 3 and Adobe Media Player software."*

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioned... Contrary to what was said here, vimeo allows hotlinking own videos, if you are using one of there premium-accounts.
But if you do so, you have to run your own responsive-scripts to choose the best video-source (network-speed, viewport-size).

[image]